# How to set equal number of ticks for two subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two subplots of horizontal bars done in `matplotlib`. For the first subplot, the number of y-axis ticks is appropriate, but I'm unable to figure out why specifying number of ticks for the second subplot is coming out to be wrong. This is the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Plot separate subplots for genders
fig, (axes1, axes2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2,
                                   sharex=False,
                                   sharey=False,
                                   figsize=(15,10))

labels = list(out.index)
x = ["20%", "40%", "60%", "80%", "100%"]
y = np.arange(len(out))
width = 0.5
axes1.barh(y, female_distr, width, color="olive",
        align="center", alpha=0.8)
axes1.ticks_params(nbins=6)
axes1.set_yticks(y)
axes1.set_yticklabels(labels)
axes1.set_xticklabels(x)
axes1.yaxis.grid(False)
axes1.set_xlabel("Occurence (%)")
axes1.set_ylabel("Language")
axes1.set_title("Language Distribution (Women)")

axes2.barh(y, male_distr, width, color="chocolate",
        align="center", alpha=0.8)
axes2.locator_params(nbins=6)
axes2.set_yticks(y)
axes2.set_yticklabels(labels)
axes2.set_xticklabels(x)
axes2.yaxis.grid(False)
axes2.set_xlabel("Occurence (%)")
axes2.set_ylabel("Language")
axes2.set_title("Language Distribution (Men)")
```

The rest of the objects like `out` are simple data frames that I don't think need to be described here. The above code returns the following plot:
[image: horizontal bars]
I would like the second subplot to have equal number of ticks but experimenting with `nbins` always results in either more or fewer ticks than the first subplot.

Comment: The problem is not that your percentages go above 100%?

Comment: Not that. I want to divide the ticks in such a manner so as both the plots are plotted within the ticks that I have defined. The first subplot is fine although I could improve it by including the last 100% mark as well. But the second plot is not including the ticks properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you want your two plots to have the same x-axis, why not use `sharex=True`?

```
x_ticks = [0,20,40,60,80,100]

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True)
ax1.set_xticks(x_ticks)
ax1.set_xticklabels(['{:.0f}%'.format(x) for x in x_ticks])
ax1.set_xlim(0,100)
ax1.grid(True, axis='x')
ax2.grid(True, axis='x')
```

[image]